# Find missing doc

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I have 1M docs in my index. The docs have an "order" key which is the unique order number of the document starting at 1 for the first doc, 1M for the last.

Some of the documents are missing. Is there an efficient way (a query) to find them? The only solution I found is bisection. Search for how many docs have order < 1M/2 gives you the halves in which the docs are missing etc..

Comment: so from 1-1,000,000 you are assured to have a representative for each doc, and if you don't it's a defect?

Comment: Imagine the docs are pages of a book with 1M pages where some pages are missing. Each doc contains the page number. So, you have 999900 docs/pages in elastic like { ...something not important... , page_number: 123} and so, and you are looking for 100 missing page numbers.

Comment: Yeah, you need to do a binary tree algo and recursively find them. So like you said in your question, query then look at count, count wrong, query upper half, count wrong, query upper half, etc.